# OSX 10.7 and up file sharing issue

Tags: windows, macos, file-sharing, osx-mountain-lion

first question here. Be gentle with me.

So....my question.

Since I upgraded from OSX 10.6 to 10.7 (then all the way up to 10.8.2). When I share files with my windows PC. It can see my entire mac hard drive.

In system prefs. I enable file sharing, then enable windows file sharing and pick my mac user account that windows has to authenticate with. I've only selected 2 folders to share (movies and downloads). Yet when I connect to my mac on windows, I put in my mac UN&PW and boom, I've got full access to my entire mac hard drive.

Anyone know of a fix for this? I've scoured through the apple support forums and I'm not alone. No one seems to have come up with any solutions though.

Cheers in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing the entire hard drive because the user you are logging in as is an administrator.

Notice this line on the File Sharing pane:
"File Sharing allows other users to access shared folders on this computer and **allows administrators to access all volumes.**"

The solution is to create a sharing only account in OS X and add that user to SMB sharing. Then give the new user read / write (or just read if that's what you're looking for) permission on those two folders.

Comment: Worked a treat. It never used to so this on 10.6.8 even when I was using the admin profile. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you provide your full login credentials (name and password), then you will have full access, much like when you log in when sitting at your Mac. This is not a bug or something that needs fixing.

However, when you connect to your Mac as a Guest and/or without logging in, *that's* when your Movies and Downloads folders should be available. The sharing setup you've configured is for non-system users, such as yourself.